# Cannot change the data type in the data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `df` looks like this:

```
        birth_year  person
    0       1980         0
    1       1981         1
    2       1982         2
    3       1983         3
    4       1984         4
```

the `birth_year` column looks like numbers but when I check the data type
`df['birth_year'].dtype` the result is `dtype('O')`

so I thought it might actually be a string, and tried to convert it to numbers with `df['birth_year'].astype('int')`but got an error:

```
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'decimal' codec can't encode characters in position 
    0-3: invalid decimal Unicode string
```

After a little googling I came to understand (might be wrongly) that there seems to be some invisible characters in it. when accessing the values `df['birth_year'][0]` the value I got is `1980L`, rather than `1980`.

so what exactly is the data type, and how can I convert it to integers? I read somewhere that if the returned data type is `dtype('O')`, it usually means it's a string, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Try `df['birth_year'].astype(int)`, not `'int'`.

Comment: you could try `df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`

Comment: Tried `df['birth_year'].astype(int)`, and got the same error

Comment: `df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` this works:) the data type is now float64. thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like your birth_year has some hidden characters, the alignment of your output suggests you have some values/characters maybe 2 characters as the output should be right aligned to the column header, the fact the dtype is `float64` may suggest you have invalid string values so these are now `NaN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert normally using `df['birth_year'].astype(int)` but it seems you have invalid values, using `df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` will coerce invalid values to `NaN` which may or may not be what you desire as this changes the dtype to `float64` rather than `int64`.

It's best to look at the invalid string values to determine why they failed to convert.

So you could do `df[df.convert_objects(convert_numeric).isnull()]` to get the rows that have invalid 'birth_year' values